# Question about reduced residue system

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $1,2,.......,p-1$ be a reduced residue system mod $p$ where $p$ is a prime number. If $\gcd\left(k,p\right)=1$ for an integer $k$ then we can say $k,2k,\dots,k(p-1)$ is also a reduced residue system mod $p$. My question is  why the following holds

$$1*2*\dots*p-1 \equiv k*2k*....*k(p-1)(\mod\text{ } p)$$

My second question is  if $$xt \equiv x (\mod\text{ } p)$$ where $x$ and $t$ are integers and the $\gcd(x,p)=1$, why can we cancel the $x$?

Comment: $xt\equiv x\pmod p$ means $p$ divides $xt-x=x(t-1)$ while $p$ does not divide $x,$ so $p$ divides $t-1,$ i.e. $t\equiv1\pmod p.$

Comment: Since $k, 2k, \dots, k(p-1)$ form a reduced system modulo $p$, they are, in some order, congruent to $1,2,\dots,p-1$, so the two products are congruent.

Comment: @joriki: I got it by using the fermat's little theorem. Thanks!

Comment: Using Fermat's Theorem may not be the best way, since this is one of the standard ways to prove Fermat's Theorem.

Answer (score 2):

You've multiplied by $k^{p-1}$, which by [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) is $1\bmod p$.

The second question has already been answered by awllower in a comment.

Comment: Hello joriki, I haven't gone over Fermat's little theorem yet.

Comment: @TheMathNoob: Then you should add context to the question and state what results you're willing to use in the proof.

Comment: @TheMathNoob Your other questions are on quadratic reciprocity, so I think it's time to look at Fermat's little theorem now.

Comment: Sure, so far I have been working on euler's criterion and wilson's theorem. I am just wondering  if it can be shown that the latter holds by just using the basics of congruence and reduced residue system.

Comment: @TheMathNoob: OK, I'll delete my answer. I don't know what's part of "the basics of reduced residue system" for you. Anyway, these comments won't be visible to everyone once the answer is deleted; you should add the information to the question itself.

Comment: Wait, I am gonna try to work on the fermat's little theorem for a while to see if I can understand your claim.

Comment: It looks like it's not that hard , so we can conclude by the wilson's theorem and the fermat's little theorem $k^{p-1}*(p-1)! \equiv -1 (mod$ $ p)$